# THREE.JS Shadow not casting - Spotlight

Tags: three.js

With THREE.JS, I am currently using a SpotLight. 
I have a MeshLambertMaterial (4 girls) which is supposed to cast a shadow to the picture behind (Mansion), but not sure why it isn't.

[image: a busy cat]

My code so far with the spotlight

```
let spotLight = new THREE.SpotLight( 0xFFFFFF, 1);
spotLight.castShadow = true;
spotLight.position.set( 10, 5, 100 );
spotLight.target.position.set(0, 5, 0);
spotLight.shadowCameraNear = 20;
spotLight.shadowCameraFov = 30;
spotLight.shadowBias = 0.0001;
spotLight.shadowCameraVisible = true;

scene.add( spotLight );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your "4 girls" object, set .castShadow = true; and on your mansion image, set .receiveShadow = true;